# Python 3.5.2 Whats the error while calling function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a program for finding the distance between two coordinates. Can somebody help me where i am going wrong?

Code:

```
from math import *
prompt= input('Enter the coordinates \n')
x= input()
x1= input()
y= input()
y1= input()
def dist(x,y,x1,y1):
  dx=x1-x
  dy=y1-y
  return sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
print ('The distance/Radius is: \n')
dist(x,y,x1,y1)
```

Comment: Presumably you're being told that it can't subtract strings... wonder why that would be?

Answer (score 3):

My Solution:

```
x= int(input())
x1= int(input())
y= int(input())
y1= int(input())
def dist(x,y,x1,y1):
    dx=x1-x
    dy=y1-y
    return ((dx**2 + dy**2)**(0.5))
print('The distance/Radius is:')
print(dist(x,y,x1,y1))
```

input:

```
1
2
2
3
```

Output:

```
The distance/Radius is: 
1.4142135623730951
```

You have to convert `input()` into `integer` before performing calculations. And for performing square root here, i do math calculation as `sqrt= x**(.5)`

Comment: It would be helpful to add a paragraph explaining what you've changed and why

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Thanks , I added the explanation